# App updates automatically even after uninstall?

Tags: nexus-7, uninstallation, application-autoupdate

I recently uninstalled an app called `All in one toolbox` from Nexus 7 tablet, but this morning after I finished updating the Chrome browser, in the notifications panel I can see that somehow `All in one toolbox` got updates, but I can't find it anywhere on the installed apps list
[image]
How did 
this happen?
Or is this app still present on the tablet somewhere, and if it is, how and where do I find it?

--- EDIT ---
This app was uninstalled by long pressing on it's icon  in the main menu, and then dragging it to uninstall, if that makes any difference.

Comment: If you click on that notification, can you still see the All-in-One app in the list of recently updated apps?

Comment: unfortunately I've already cleared all the notifications, but if I remember I couldn't see it in any list, neither the one that comes up when I click on that notification, nor any of the other downloaded and running apps list that we can find in settings. What I am worried about it that is it possible for the app to leave some of it's components behind even after I have told the device uninstall it, so that it doesn't show up on lists but it's files and some of it's activities remain behind

Comment: Since I downloaded this particular app from google playstore I'm hoping it's nothing dangerous, but if it is indeed possible for an app to linger around unseen even after I have uninstalled it, I should know about it

Comment: In app information, clicking an app in the app manager, there are two types of uninstall: Uninstall and Uninstall Updates. by using the launcher shortcut probabily it clicked Uninstall Updates, try to uninstall it again and tell us

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug. Try this:

1. Open **Play Store**.
2. Navigate to *My Apps*, then go to the *All* section.
3. Delete the app from your account (usually by a small X in the top right corner of the list entry).

See diagram below:

[image: My apps]

If it does not give you the X to delete the app from your account, click on the app in that list and uninstall it from the app's Play Store screen.